# why a array-pointer gives me different values

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

The code goes

```
#include<stdio.h>

int sumOfElements_new(int *A, int size){ // int *A or int A[] same thing

    int i, sum = 0; // remember arrays decay as pointers in other functions besides main
    for (i =0; i<size;i++){
        sum += A[i]; // A[i] = *(A+i)-> value at that address
    }
    return sum;
}

int main(){

    int A[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
    int size = sizeof(A)/sizeof(A[0]);
    int total = sumOfElements_new(&A[0], size);
    printf("%d\n", &A[4]);
    printf("Sum of elements = %d\n", total);
    printf("Size of A = %d and size of A[0] = %d\n", sizeof(A), sizeof(A[0]));
    return 0;
}
```

Now when I do something like this

```
int total = sumOfElements_new(&A[3], size);
```

the result is

```
Sum of elements = 30
Size of A = 20 and size of A[0] = 4
```

whenever I use &A[1] to any &A[6], it gives me different values.
Then why calling it in

```
int size = sizeof(A)/sizeof(A[0]);
```

gives me the correct answer of the Sum of the elements but, using &A[1-6] the answer goes up and its not even memory address??

Comment: What type is `&A[4]`? Why would you attempt to print it as an `int` with `printf("%d\n", &A[4]);`? That invokes *Undefined Behavior*.

Answer (score 2):

Given how you define `size`, (e.g) `int size = sizeof(A)/sizeof(A[0]);` you can [only] do:

```
sumOfElements_new(&A[0],size)
```

If you use (e.g.) `&A[3]`, you can't pass:

```
sumOfElements_new(&A[3],size)
```

because you're telling the function to sum past the *end* of the array. This is UB (undefined behavior). The program will fetch the data beyond the end, but that data is *random* (it is just whatever *happens* to be there).

You have to shorten the size/length you pass to the function. What you'd want is:

```
sumOfElements_new(&A[3],size - 3)
```

---

**UPDATE:**

> May want to comment on `printf("%d\n", &A[4]);` as well..

This presents another issue. You [probably] want to print the *value* of the element of the `A` that has index `4`.

The indexing is correct (i.e. it does *not* go beyond the end of the array), but you're passing the *address* of that element and *not* its value.

With your original code, if you compiled with warnings enabled (e.g. using the `-Wall` option--which you should *always* do, IMO), the compiler would flag this statement.

That's because you're passing an address [which on modern x86 cpus is probably 64 bits]. That's an *unsigned* quantity and you're trying to print it in decimal using only 32 bits [because an `int` is usually only 32 bits].

So, to print the *value*, you'd probably want:

```
printf("%d\n", A[4]);
```

*If* you *truly* wanted to print the *address* of that element [a more advanced usage], you could do:

```
printf("%p\n", &A[4]);
```

Comment: May want to comment on `printf("%d\n", &A[4]);` as well..

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Thanks, David. Right you are. Hope you are safe and well in these special times.

Comment: Masked and distanced... and worried when my kids come home from school....